# JSON Parsing: org.json.JSON.typeMismatch

Tags: java, android, json

I am attempting to parse JSON from a URL, I think I have tried a 100 different ways but so far I haven't found the correct solution. I believe the problem I am having is with the data structure from the JSON I am receiving.  Each has a name starting with"0" and increasing to till last one. I want to take all these companies and put them into an arraylist.

```
    public static String url = "http://api.richmondsystemengineering.com/v1/?query_type=rva_card_get_businesses&appkey=51e53e510ecc14e4b2bde952f0c589f0";

    public static void getData(Context context) {
    // Hashmap for ListView

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = null;
    HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
        response = httpClient.execute(getMethod);

        // CONVERT RESPONSE TO STRING
        String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

        // CONVERT RESPONSE STRING TO JSON ARRAY
        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(result);

        // ITERATE THROUGH AND RETRIEVE CLUB FIELDS
        int n = ja.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            // GET INDIVIDUAL JSON OBJECT FROM JSON ARRAY
            JSONObject c = ja.getJSONObject(i);
            Log.e("name", c.getString("phone"));


            // Storing each json item in variable
            companyName = c.getString("name");
            companyEmail = c.getString("email");
            companyAddress = c.getString("address");
            companyCity = c.getString("city");
            companyZip = c.getString("zip");
            companyDescription = c.getString("description");



            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("name", companyName);
            map.put("email", companyEmail);
            map.put("address", companyAddress);
            map.put("city", companyCity);
            map.put("zip", companyZip);
            map.put("description", companyDescription);
            contactList.add(map);


        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        error = true;

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Then on my Logcat I get:

```
    org.json.JSONException: Value {"EAT_subcat":"farm, market and grocery","phone":"(804) 780-0086","WORK_subcat":"advertising","RID":"6","state":"","featured":"1","EAT":"1","city":"Richmond","DRINK":"1","distance":5532.3,"PLAY_subcat":"indoor and outdoor recreational activities","ENJOY_subcat":"entertainment and landmarks","updated":"2014-07-09 00:48:50","created":"2014-09-17 13:07:16","description":"Bistro 27 is a lively European bistro located in downtown Richmond, Virginia at the corner of Broad and Adams. With our floor-to-ceiling, wrap around windows and airy 20 foot ceilings, Twenty Seven offers a dining experience like no other in Richmond. Our menu is influenced by the hearty, healthy cuisines of Italy and France and features something for everyone's taste. Twenty Seven's wine lists ranges from inexpensive, little known gems to world class award winners. Parking is free at the corner of Adam and Grace Street, in the southwest corner. Look for the Bistro 27 sign  ","SHOP_subcat":"home garden goods and electronics","zip4":"0","name":"Bistro 27","longitude":"-77.442953","LIVE_subcat":"health fitness and edu classes","fname":"","zip":"23220","logo":"Pic"
at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:553)
at com.rse.rvacard.SearchActivity.getData(SearchActivity.java:167)
at com.rse.rvacard.SearchActivity.onCreate(SearchActivity.java:79)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5586)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2402)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2497)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:168)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1306)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5678)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: convert response to `JSONObject` instead of `JSONArray` because response string contain `JSONObject` instead of `JSONArray`

Comment: Sorry, a little slow when it comes to parsing data. How exactly do I do that?

Comment: copy the result please.

Comment: The Json result it pretty large, but here is a link to it. I put it in Jsonlint.com to validate.   http://api.richmondsystemengineering.com/v1/?query_type=rva_card_get_businesses&appkey=51e53e510ecc14e4b2bde952f0c589f0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About Json :
[ {in these brackets} ,{ there is an array}, {of objects} ] 
{in these brackets is an just an object}

You said " hey, get me that JSONArray"(omg it rhymes!) and Eclipse is telling you: "You crazy? I dont see an array" (hidden message is there's just an object, not an array)

More about json [here](http://www.w3schools.com/json/).

```
    // CONVERT RESPONSE TO STRING
    String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

    // CONVERT RESPONSE STRING TO JSON OBJECT
    JSONObject c = new JSONObject (result);

        // Storing each json item in variable
        companyName = c.getString("name");
        companyEmail = c.getString("email");
        companyAddress = c.getString("address");
        companyCity = c.getString("city");
        companyZip = c.getString("zip");
        companyDescription = c.getString("description");}
```